# lambda-like functions in R?

Tags: r, lambda

I’m required to use/learn R for a new lecture at uni and I’m currently struggling a bit with its syntax. I want to plot (via `curve`) a simple function, but I can’t seem to get it working with an inline lambda-like function.

I’ve tried the following:

```
> curve( function(x) x^2 )
Error in curve(function(x) x^2) : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

When I however store the function in a variable first, it works:

```
> quad <- function(x) x^2
> curve( quad )
```

Is such an inline use not allowed in R? Is there any other way to make this work without defining an extra function? Thanks!

Comment: This works: `curve( x^2 )`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to look at the source of `curve` to appreciate what is happening (just type `curve` at the prompt and press enter).

There you can find how the expression passed is parsed.

The only way a function is discovered as being just that, is when only its name is passed along (see the `is.name`part). If that is not the case, the expression is called for every `x`. In your case: for every `x`, the result is a function, which is not a happy thought for plotting...

So in short: no you cannot do what you tried, but as @ROLO indicated, you can immediately pass the function body, which will be parsed as an expression (and should contain `x`). If this holds multiple statements, just enclose them in curly braces.

Comment: Didn’t know that simply typing the function would show the source, thanks for that ^^ And I didn’t try just typing the function body, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 78):

Just for completeness. You can use "lambda-like" (anonymous) functions in R but if you want to put them to immediate use, you need to enclose the function definition in parentheses or curly braces:

```
(function (x) x+1) (1)
{function (x,y) x^y} (2,3)
```

In the case of `curve` the first argument is either expression or a function name - but if it is a function name then it is first converted to an expression. (See first few lines in the source code of `curve`). So if its' not a function name, you'll need an expression – which may contain a "lambda" function:

```
curve((function (x) x^2)(x))
```

If you want to use a function (as opposed to its name) as the argument, you can use plot.function:

```
plot(function(x) x^2)
```

Comment: with `magrittr` one can now to something like `1 %>% {.+1}` instead of `{function (x) x+1}(1)`

Comment: This could replace all lambda functions! epic!

Comment: R's lazy evaluation of function arguments, as exhibited here (and @ROLO's comment to OP), never ceases to seem like black magic to me.  The undefined argument, `x`, has cryptic meaning that only arises in the context of the (hidden) body of the function being called.

Comment: @merv There is nothing specific to lazy evaluation here. The `x` in `curve(x^2)` is not undefined, but it is evaluated in nonstandard way. (Perhaps you meant nonstandard, not lazy evaluation. It can be confusing, yes. Like in `library(pryr)`, pryr can be quoted or not, and it works out the same. However, it has to be quoted in `install.packages("pryr")`. You can see nonstandard evaluation whenever `substitute` is used in a function.

Comment: Probably the simplest example of lazy (non)evaluation is `(function(x) 1)()`. This evaluates to `1` even though a required argument was not supplied.  The argument (x) would be evaluated only when first used but this never happens in this example.

Comment: This doesn't mean you can supply anything as `x`, it must be parseable (for example, "``" [two backticks] and "ho ho" won't go through).

Comment: @lebatsnok Thanks for the added info.  Yeah, I get that `curve` works because it uses non-standard evaluation to parse the `expr` argument.  But that still needs lazy evaluation or else `x` would resolve as undefined prior to reaching the function body.  I was mostly commenting on this from the standpoint of how other languages don't have this possibility to postpone (and reinterpret) argument expression parsing.

Answer (score 38):

From `R 4.1` on, you can use `\(x)` lambda-like shorthand:

> R now provides a shorthand notation for creating anonymous functions,
> e.g. \(x) x + 1 is parsed as function(x) x + 1.

With `function(x) x^2`:

```
(\(x) x^2)(2)
#[1] 4
```

This can be used with `curve` :

```
curve((\(x) x^2)(x))
```

[image]

But as stated in comments, in this case an expression is more straightforward :

```
curve(x^2)
```