# Is there a better clean approach to single-use functions in R?

Tags: r, lambda

In a lot of cases, I need to write some code that makes up a logical bloc and it feels right to place it in a function. However, being used only once, it makes it more cumbersome to move the code away from where it is applied and give it a single-use name thus polluting the namespace.

Today, I was experimenting and I also came across a question about [lambda expressions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833173/lambda-like-functions-in-r). So I implemented my logic as following:

```
x <- (function(charsBase, n, m) {
  z <- apply(
    matrix(
        sample(unique(charsBase), n*m*3, replace = TRUE)
        , nrow = n*3, ncol = m
    )
    , 1
    , paste, collapse="")
  head(unique(z), n)
}) (LETTERS, 1000, 3)
```

Questions:

1. Is there a better way of creating a lambda in R?
2. While the namespace is apparently kept clean, how about the memory? In my experience, R usually leaks when you create / remove object in the global environment. If extensive allocation / freeing is done within the function, would this keep the memory under control?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example about "memory leaks" when you create or remove an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `with` with a list or data-frame as first argument. For example:

```
result <- with(list(a=3, b=4), {
    foo <- a + b
    foo^2
})
```

This keeps the global environment clean, because the part enclosed in brackets is evaluated in a separate environment that is destroyed after the evaluation takes place.

However, in my experience it can become cumbersome to program in this style. Sometimes I find more practical to clean up unwanted objects with `rm()` when they're no longer needed. It's not as elegant, this I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `local` with shorter lines and more readable code:

```
x <- local({
  charsBase <- LETTERS
  n <- 1000
  m <- 3
  sam <- sample(unique(charsBase), n*m*3, replace = TRUE)
  mtx <- matrix(sam, nrow = n*3, ncol = m)
  z <- apply(mtx, 1, paste, collapse="")
  head(unique(z), n)
})
```

Nothing of the above "leaks" to the global environment unless you explicitly use  global assignment with `<<-`. The value of the last "thing" evaluated within the curly brackets becomes the value of x. You can get identical result with ...

```
local({
  charsBase <- LETTERS
  n <- 1000
  m <- 3
  sam <- sample(unique(charsBase), n*m*3, replace = TRUE)
  mtx <- matrix(sam, nrow = n*3, ncol = m)
  z <- apply(mtx, 1, paste, collapse="")
  x <<- head(unique(z), n)   # notice the wyrd assignment operator
})
```

... I'd say it's less elegant but then again, it's a matter of preference.

A useful trick I sometimes use when experimenting is ...

```
local(browser())
```

You don't have to keep track of the assignments, everything is temporary unless you use global assignment.