# hand over function current loop number

Tags: r

Since it's a short question I'll leave out regular background information (if you need, I'll add it).
Finally there is a data frame called Coefficients

```
Serial_number    Fixed_effects_beta_0    Fixed_effects_beta_1    Fixed_effects_beta_2    Fixed_effects_beta_3    Random_effects_beta_0    Random_effects_beta_1    Random_effects_beta_2    Random_effects_beta_3    p0_fixed    p1_fixed    p2_fixed    p3_fixed    p0_random    p1_random    p2_random    p3_random    Fitted_Voltage
1    912009913    1.238401    13.19572    -0.08379988    1.366747    -0.039642999    -0.40767221    -0.25476169    -0.11315457    -11.92334    0.1177605    -0.0003777831    4.328852e-07    0.56414753    -0.006946270    2.736287e-05    -3.583906e-08    352.9476
(...)
```

and for each row I want to apply the function

```
inverse = function (f, lower = lower_limit, upper = 450) {
  function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower_limit, upper = upper)[1]
#  function (y) polyroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower_limit, upper = upper)[1]
}

function_to_observe = inverse((function(x=150)
  exp(
    exp(
    sum(
        Coefficients[running_row,"p0_fixed"] * x^0,
        Coefficients[running_row,"p1_fixed"] * x^1,
        Coefficients[running_row,"p2_fixed"] * x^2,
        Coefficients[running_row,"p3_fixed"] * x^3
     ))
    )
  )
  , 50, 450)
```

by making use of values stored in each row and in certain columns of the data frame as follows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Coefficients)){
    Coefficients[i,"Fitted_Voltage"]<- function_to_observe(150)
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work since `Coefficients[i,"Fitted_Voltage"]<- function_to_observe(150)` does not take care of the different rows of Coefficients.
What's a remedy? Whyever I cannot do the following:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Coefficients)){
    Coefficients[i,"Fitted_Voltage"]<- inverse((function(x=150)
  exp(
    exp(
    sum(
        Coefficients[i,"p0_fixed"] * x^0,
        Coefficients[i,"p1_fixed"] * x^1,
        Coefficients[i,"p2_fixed"] * x^2,
        Coefficients[i,"p3_fixed"] * x^3
     ))
    )
  )
  , 50, 450)
}
```

This yields:

```
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : 
  incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

```
# Update:
With the help of mathdotrandom I tried a bit and get the following:
lower_limit<- 0
function_to_observe<- inverse((function(x=150)
  exp(
    exp(
      sum(
        Coefficients[i,"p0_fixed"] * x^0,
        Coefficients[i,"p1_fixed"] * x^1,
        Coefficients[i,"p2_fixed"] * x^2,
        Coefficients[i,"p3_fixed"] * x^3
      ))))
  , 50, 550
)


inverse = function (f, lower = lower_limit, upper = 450) {
  function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower_limit, upper = upper)[1]
}

for(i in 1:nrow(Coefficients)){
  Coefficients[i, "Fitted_Voltage"]<- function_to_observe(150)
}
Coefficients["Fitted_Voltage"]
```

which yields reasonable values:

```
   Fitted_Voltage
1        352.9476
2        352.9476
3        352.9476
4        352.9476
5        352.9476
6        352.9476
7        352.9476
8        352.9476
9        352.9476
10       352.9476
11       352.9476
12       352.9476
13       352.9476
14       352.9476
15       352.9476
```

Though I do not understand the syntax I guess this is correct since it does what it should.

Comment: The error message is adequate. You are trying to assign the function (inner function expects parameter x) to the entry in the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function(x=150) does not run the function but sets x as a default parameter of 150. So you try to put a function definition into your data.frame. Thats why it complains about the type closure(function).  Easiest is to give the function a name and define it outside of the for loop and then call it.

If you really want to use it as lambda function checkout this question and lebatsnok answer: [lambda-like functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833173/lambda-like-functions-in-r)

The inverse function should not return a function but a number. The uniroot function expects a function, so f should be a function as you did. R will actually lookup the value of i or running_row from above if you don't put it as a parameter.

```
Coefficients <- data.frame("Fitted_Voltage"=c(0,0), "p0_fixed"=c(10^-1, 10^-2),
                           "p1_fixed"=c(10^-2, 10^-3), "p2_fixed"=c(10^-3, 10^-4),
                           "p3_fixed"=c(10^-4, 10^-5))

f <- function(x=150)exp(exp(sum(Coefficients[running_row,"p0_fixed"] * x^0, 
                                Coefficients[running_row,"p1_fixed"] * x^1,                                
                                Coefficients[running_row,"p2_fixed"] * x^2,
                                Coefficients[running_row,"p3_fixed"] * x^3)))

inverse = function (f, lower_limit, upper = 450) {
     y = (f(lower_limit) + f(upper))/2
     uniroot(function(x)(f(x)-y), lower = lower_limit, upper = upper)[1]
}
for(running_row in 1:nrow(Coefficients)){
    Coefficients[i, "Fitted_Voltage"] <- inverse(f,-1,1)
}
```

But your function is always positive because you used exp and exp(x) >0 forall x, so uniroot can not find a zero of that function. Also polyroot can only find zeros of polynomials but you are using an exponentail function. Are you sure that your function should look like: e^(e^(c_0 + c_1*x + c_2*x^2 + c_3*x^3))?
I subtract a value in inverse to make it have a root but i dont know if this makes any sense in your context. Also because of double exponential the function gets big really fast, so even for small Coefficients it returns Infinity for lower limit 50 and upper 450, so i needed to do -1 and 1 as limits to get some results. But this should be somehow similar to how you want it.

Comment: Thanks! How can I define the definition outside when I need different rows/coefficients within that function? Can I somehow pass the "i" of the loop maybe to the function?

Comment: i guess by making i a paramater of that function

Comment: How? I know how to do that in c++ but R is still kind of a mystery for me..

Comment: At first thank you for the new information! I guess you set up the right syntax but I cannot see through it. The calls of function, inverse and the definitions confuse me. At least I can respond to your concern regarding the uniroot function: In my code lines the calculation is correct (for every row) but apparently not in your case. I'll try to merge it somehow but I'm afraid this R scenario is a bit over my head right now..

Comment: Can you please have a look again on the updated question? I think it's correct now but though I would like to have it revised. Your code lines were not quite exact the ones I needed but I would say you got it almost resp. without them I wouldn't have got it. Therefore I will accept your answer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Following mathdotrandom's suggestion. You can define function outside. Try this:

```
inner.f <- function(x=150, i){
exp(
exp(
  sum(
    Coefficients[i,"p0_fixed"] * x^0,
    Coefficients[i,"p1_fixed"] * x^1,
    Coefficients[i,"p2_fixed"] * x^2,
    Coefficients[i,"p3_fixed"] * x^3
  ))
)
}
```

then (if you want x to be set to 150)

```
Coefficients[i,"Fitted_Voltage"]<- inverse(inner.f(150, i), 50, 450)
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this generates the same error.