# What is the equivalent of \(x) in lower versions of r?

Tags: r

I have a piece of code that works in r version 4.2.0 but fails to work in r version 4.0.5. This is due to the part of the code that gives a variable of a data_table once at a time. The code is :

```r
require(stringr)
require(data.table)

# Create an example data table
cat_var <- c("rock", "indie", "rock", "rock", "pop", "indie", NA, "rock")
cat_var_2 <- c("blue", "green", "red", "red", "blue", NA, "green", "blue")
target_var <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
df <- data.table("categorical_variable" = cat_var, "categorical_variable_2" = cat_var_2, "target_variable" =  target_var)

nms <- c("categorical_variable", "categorical_variable_2")
countInClass <- df[, lapply(setNames(nm=nms), \(g) ave(target_variable, get(g), FUN = cumsum) - target_variable)]
```

When I run this code in r version 4.0.5 I get an error for the variable `countInClass`. How can I modify it so that it runs without any problems. I removed `\(g)` part as that is the part that yields the error but I need to replace it with the variable and I do not know how to.

Comment: `\(x)` is equivalent to `function(x)` in lambda-like (single line) functions from R 4.1.0.

Comment: @Maël what can I replace it with so that the code runs in r version 4.0.5?

Comment: you can replace by `function(x)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lambda-like functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833173/lambda-like-functions-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is a syntactic shortcut for the `function` keyword starting with R 4.1.0. From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html):

> ```
> function( arglist ) expr
> \( arglist ) expr
> ```

In fact, we can verify the syntactic equivalence ourselves by looking at an unevaluated expression:

```
quote(\(arglist) expr)
# function(arglist) expr
```

Comment: With what alternative can I replace it with so that the code runs in 4.0.5

Comment: @moli Well, with `function`. It’s just a shortcut — they’re identical.