# Selecting the top X values of each individual column in R

Tags: r, sorting

Say you have the following data set.

```
df1<-matrix(data = 1:10,
            nrow = 5,
            ncol = 5)
colnames(df1)=c("a","b","c","d","e")
```

How would you extract the top X values from each individual column as a new data frame?

The expected output would be something like this (for the top 3 values in each column

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 | 5 | 10 | 5 |
| 4 | 9 | 4 | 9 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 | 3 | 8 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to apply a function to each column (`MARGIN = 2`). Here, the function is `\(x) head(sort(x, decreasing = T), 3)`, which sorts the column by decreasing order, and select the top three values (`head(x, 3)`).

```r
apply(df1, 2, \(x) head(sort(x, decreasing = T), 3))

     a  b c  d e
[1,] 5 10 5 10 5
[2,] 4  9 4  9 4
[3,] 3  8 3  8 3
```

<sub>Note: `\(x)` is a shorthand for `function(x)` in [lambda-like functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67587195/13460602) since 4.1.0.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

We can *sort*, then use *head*:

```
head(apply(df1, 2, sort, decreasing = TRUE), 3)
#      a  b c  d e
# [1,] 5 10 5 10 5
# [2,] 4  9 4  9 4
# [3,] 3  8 3  8 3
```