# Calculate mean and standard deviation for subgroups

Tags: r

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation for subgroups every column in my dataset.
The membership of the subgroups is based on the values in the column of interest and these subgroups are specific to each column of interest.

```
# Example data
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(baseline = runif(100), `Week0_12` = runif(100), `Week12_24` = runif(100))
```

So for column `Baseline`, a row may be assigned to another subgroup than for column `Week0_12`.

I can of course create these 'subgroup columns' manually for each column and then calculate the statistics for each column by column subgroup:

```
df$baseline_subgroup <- ifelse(df$baseline < 0.2, "subgroup_1", "subgroup_2")
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, .(mean = mean(baseline), sd = sd(baseline)), by = baseline_subgroup]
```

Giving this output:

```
   baseline_subgroup       mean         sd
1:        subgroup_2 0.58059314 0.22670071
2:        subgroup_1 0.09793105 0.05317809
```

Doing this for every column separately is too much repetition, especially given that I have many columns my actual data.

```
df$Week0_12_subgroup <- ifelse(df$Week0-12 < 0.2, "subgroup_1", "subgroup_2")
df[, .(mean = mean(Week0_12), sd = sd(Week0_12 )), by = Week0_12_subgroup ]

df$Week12_24_subgroup <- ifelse(df$Week0-12 < 0.2, "subgroup_1", "subgroup_2")
df[, .(mean = mean(Week12_24), sd = sd(Week12_24)), by = Week12_24_subgroup ]
```

What is a more elegant approach to do this?

Comment: Next time use `set.seed()` when using functions such as `runif()` so we ensure reproducibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse method that gives an easy-to-read and easy-to-plot output:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(baseline = runif(100), 
                 `Week0_12` = runif(100), 
                 `Week12_24` = runif(100))

df2 <- df %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), list(mean_subgroup1 = ~mean(.x[.x < 0.2]), 
                                      sd_subgroup1   = ~sd(.x[.x < 0.2]),
                                      mean_subgroup2 = ~mean(.x[.x > 0.2]),
                                      sd_subgroup2   = ~sd(.x[.x > 0.2])))) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = '^(.*)_(.*)_(.*$)',
               names_to = c('time', 'measure', 'subgroup')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = measure, values_from = value)

df2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   time      subgroup    mean     sd
#>   <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 baseline  subgroup1 0.0979 0.0532
#> 2 baseline  subgroup2 0.581  0.227 
#> 3 Week0_12  subgroup1 0.117  0.0558
#> 4 Week0_12  subgroup2 0.594  0.225 
#> 5 Week12_24 subgroup1 0.121  0.0472
#> 6 Week12_24 subgroup2 0.545  0.239

ggplot(df2, aes(time, mean, group = subgroup)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd, color = subgroup),
                width = 0.1) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for.  However, the code returns an error when I use it on the example data: `Error in context_peek():`. Could you provide the full script you used?

Comment: @mivandev I have updated as a full reprex. Copying and pasting this exact code should produce the exact same output in a clean R session

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron, but the error is still there. I was able to fix it by changing the `summarize()` call to `dplyr::summarize()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` to apply a subgroup function across each column

i. e.

```
# list to house dfs of summary statistics 
summaries <- list()

subgroup <- function(x){
# x is the column that we are interested in
df$current_subgroup<- ifelse(x < 0.2, "subgroup_1", "subgroup_2")

library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
summaries.append(df[, .(mean = mean(baseline), sd = sd(baseline)), by = baseline_subgroup])
}

# MARGIN = 2 applies across columns
apply(df, 2, subgroup)
```

Comment: Subgroups can vary between columns and this approach does not consider that fact.

Comment: My bad. It might be helpful to put that fact in your question so that people answering know that. Using `apply(df[,c(i)], 2, vector_of_functions[i])` within a for loop, you can apply a different function to each column in the list (after creating a list of functions). [This approach to function building might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67587195/18775765)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function and apply it using `.SD`, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

f1 <- function(x){
i_mean <- mean(x); 
i_sd <- sd(x); 
list(Avg = i_mean, standard_dev = i_sd)
 }

setDT(df)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, f1), recursive = FALSE), by = baseline_subgroup][]

   baseline_subgroup baseline.Avg baseline.standard_dev Week0.12.Avg Week0.12.standard_dev Week12.24.Avg Week12.24.standard_dev
1:        subgroup_2    0.5950020            0.22556590    0.5332555             0.2651810     0.5467046              0.2912027
2:        subgroup_1    0.1006693            0.04957005    0.5947161             0.2645519     0.5137543              0.3213723
```

Comment: Subgroups can vary between columns and this approach does not consider that fact. –